# How to calculate count(customer_id) for date column (cumulative including today) from hadoop hive

Tags: hive

Is there any way to get the cumulative `count(customer_id)` for today's date and a number of days leading up to today's date, in Hive?  The date column in this format:

`20120907`

I have 2 columns in my dataset, `customer_id` and `date`.

There are also partitions in my table and some of the values in the `customer_id` column are `NULL`.  I am not sure if there are duplicates so I will use

```
count(distinct(customer_id))
```

Here is an example of my data.

```
customer_id  date
10001         20140901
10003         20141001
NULL          20150101
10007         20150102
```

Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: Show some sample data of your question. BTW: Is there  partitions in your table?

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around. I did update my question ,